# How can I get the data to create a burndown chart from Jira Greenhopper?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

How can I get the data to create a burndown chart from Jira Greenhopper?

I want to create my own burndown chart with my own graphics. Is there an api I can get the current and historical task data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the data for the Hour Burndown Chart via the [actions menu](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+the+Chart+Board) on the version you are interested in. To do this click on the "Excel (Chart Data)" link.

Alternatively, you may wish to comment on [GHS-1853](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-1853), <strike>an open</strike> a meanwhile closed issue that covers APIs for GreenHopper, with your requirements.

Comment: Thanks man! Is there a way I can automate getting this information? I direct link to the data without authentication so I can write a service to pull it daily?

Comment: Hi, did any one able to get this data using the api. I too want to create a my chart but the API seems to be unncessary complicated.